# Работа с массивом векторов C++

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь с массивом векторов. Нужно задать векторам в массиве какую-либо длину(рандомную у каждого вектора). И заполнить каждый вектор рандомными числами.

```
int m; m = Convert::ToInt32(numericUpDown1->Value); // здесь я задаю переменную и присваиваю ей значение из numericupdown
    vector<vector<int>> vc; // создаю массив векторов
    vc.resize(m); // задаю кол-во векторов
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arraySeq;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> sizeUid(1, 6);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> valueUid(-100, 100);

    std::size_t N = sizeUid(gen);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        std::vector<int> array(sizeUid(gen));
        std::generate(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [&]{
            return valueUid(gen);
        });
        arraySeq.emplace_back(std::move(array));
    }

    for(auto& array: arraySeq){
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(const auto& x: array){
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Описания используемых сущностный ищите на cppreference.com